# Creating a nested model instance (has_many relation) on the view of its parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many

I have a model A und a model B and the relation is A has_many B (and B belongs_to A). I have a model, a controller and views for A and only a model for B.
I want to create and edit the instances of B on the edit view of A ( url/a/1/edit).

I know I can create a controller for B and call those methods using a form in the view of A, but then I need to redirect back to the view of A, because I don't want actual views for B.

Is there a recommended way to do this? What I want is to not break any of the helpers rails provides (e.g. after a forward I think it's a pain to get error messages and stuff like that).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `gem "cocoon"` for nested forms You can get Documentation here https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: In case you do not need input from view, you can simply use callback methods(before_save/after_save) on Model A. So when your edit method saves the updated model A, the callbacks would be triggered and you can then in that call back edit the associated models. If you need to edit fields of nested models from view, then better use gem "cocoon" as referred by @Mayank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the model level you would use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

```
class A < ApplicationModel
  has_many :bs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bs
  validates_associated :bs
end

class B < ApplicationModel
  belongs_to :a
end
```

This lets A take attributes and create nested `bs` by passing the attribute `bs_attributes` with an array of attributes. [`validates_associated`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) can be used to ensure that A cannot be persisted of the `bs` are not also valid.

To create the [nested form fields](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)

```
<%= form_for(@a) do |f| %>
  # field on A
  <%= f.text_input :foo %>
  # creates a fields for each B associated with A.
  <%= f.fields_for(:bs) do |b| %>
    <%= b.text_input :bar %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To [whitelist nested attributes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#nested-parameters) use a hash key with an array of permitted attributes for the child records:

```
params.require(:a)
      .permit(:foo, bs_attributes: [:id, :bar])
```

When creating new records you also have to "seed" the form if you want there to be inputs present for creating nested records:

```
class AsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @a = A.new
    seed_form
  end

  def create
    @a = A.new(a_params)
    if @a.save 
      redirect_to @a
    else
      seed_form
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @a.update(a_params) 
      redirect_to @a
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def seed_form
    5.times { @a.bs.new } if @a.bs.none?
  end

  def a_params
    params.require(:a)
          .permit(:foo, bs_attributes: [:id, :bar])
  end
end
```

**Edit:**
seed_form can also just add one and do that every time. So you will always have one "empty" one to add. You need to make sure to filter out the empty one before saving if it was not filled by changing the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :bs, reject_if: proc { |attr| attr['bar'].blank? }
```

Comment: This is generally one the most complex parts of Rails to understand and I ask that you please read the documentation links in this answer throughly before asking follow up questions.

Comment: And no - you don't need the cocoon gem. It does make certain aspects of dealing with nested records easier but also abstracts away a lot of vital knowledge.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I will look into it and come back if I have follow up questions. (And mark the answer as correct once I've done it. *g*)

Comment: I just have one follow up questions right now. With this approach, everything is handled in A's controller. What would need to be different in case of design or requirements, to create a nested controller for B? Is it just for the dedicated views? Or is there any other reason to prefer one approach over the other?

Comment: Ok, I have tried to implement this exactly the same way. It works fine when I create an instance of A (with an instance of B), but when I start editing it also duplicates ALL the instances of B. There are hidden fields for the IDs of the existing instances of B though. Am I missing something?

Comment: "What would need to be different in case of design or requirements, to create a nested controller for B?" - creating a parent through the child is a bit less common but doable. You just use the same pattern but inversed. `B` should `accept_nested_attributes_for :a` (note that its singular).

Comment: It's a problem with your code, but sure I could open a new post about it. For anyone interested why this solution may create duplicates, it's because you need to allow the :id of the B model in the a_params method.
If it's not to much to ask, could the original poster please edit your answer?