# How to make a record of one model inside form of another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: User and Address

User has many addresses and Address belongs to User.

How to make a new record of Address model inside form for new User registration and immediately assign user_id(which I added to Address model) to current_user.id.

I tried to nest form_for Address.new inside form_for User.new but then I realized that it's impossible. How to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a nested model instance (has\_many relation) on the view of its parent model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423995/creating-a-nested-model-instance-has-many-relation-on-the-view-of-its-parent-m)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), check out [this guide](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes).